# how write select query in equal value

Tags: php, php-5.5

$values=AEO94 AEO96 ,how ro write select query t_assign_to==$values;i don't know how to do this

```html
<?php
include("dbconfig.php");                  
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task_employee WHERE emp_underon ='2'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);//2
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
$values=$row['emp_id'].'<br>';// i got value here like this
//AEO94 
//AE066
    if($count > 0){
    //$mysql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE t_assign_to='$values'")    
    echo $count;
    }else{
    echo "0 results";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: If you want to check for multiple values you can use in clause of sql like this "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status IN('pending','in-transit','picked-up')" which will return orders with status pending or in-transit or picked-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see small problem

```
//$values=$row['emp_id'].'<br>';// html tag is attached to value
$values = $row['emp_id'];// remove br tag
```

And add **where** before your condition

Query :   $mysql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task where t_assign_to='$values'")    ;